# Table of contents without title

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, multicol

I would like to have two-columned table of contents:

```
    \begin{multicols}{2}
          \tableofcontents
    \end{multicols}
```

But it looks wierd if I have a title included in two columns - second column is above the title. So I would like to have something like that:

```
    \section*{My content}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
          % table of contents without title
          \tableofcontents
    \end{multicols}
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Which document class are you sing?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [`article`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/article.cls) document class defined `\tableofcontents` as

```
\newcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \section*{\contentsname
        \@mkboth{%
           \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    }
```

This prints both the `\contentsname` as a `\section*` and marks the headers, after which it typesets the actual ToC (via `\@starttoc{toc}`). If you forego the header adjustments, merely renewing the `\tableofcontents` command to

```
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}[1][\contentsname]{%
  \section*{#1}
  \begin{multicols}{2}
    \@starttoc{toc}
  \end{multicols}
}
```

would suffice. This typesets a `\section*` with the contents name provided as an optional argument (default is `\contentsname`, which is `Contents` in `article`). Afterwards, if starts a two-column `multicol` environment and inserts the ToC. Here's a minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}% http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}[1][\contentsname]{%
  \section*{#1}
  \begin{multicols}{2}
    \@starttoc{toc}
  \end{multicols}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents[Table of Contents]
\section{First section}%
\subsection{First subsection}%
\subsection{Second subsection}%
\subsection{Third subsection}%
\subsection{Last subsection}%
\section{Second section}%
\subsection{First subsection}%
\subsection{Second subsection}%
\subsection{Third subsection}%
\subsection{Last subsection}%
\section{Last section}%
\subsection{First subsection}%
\subsection{Second subsection}%
\subsection{Third subsection}%
\subsection{Last subsection}%
\end{document}​
```

Comment: you might want to also include a `\mathboth` statement after the section command so to get running headers for any followup pages (if the TOC is long).

Comment: I'm too slow for this system it doesn't allow me to correct my comments after 5 min ... this should have come first: @Werner For the sake of separating document structure from document layout I would recommend to redefine `\tableofcontents` to include both `\section*` and the `multicols` environment. Then your source stays clean and you only have additions/changes in the preamble.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach: Thanks - good and clean suggestion!

Answer (score 7):

For a ToC in multiple columns you can simply use the [multitoc](http://ctan.org/pkg/multitoc) package.

```
\documentclass[11pt,english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[toc]{multitoc}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents

  \Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: The package conflicts with the tocbasic package from KOMA-script. Which is not that surprising...

Answer (score 1):

Use KOMASCRIPT article and do it this way..

```
\BeforeStartingTOC[toc]{\begin{multicols}{2}}
\AfterStartingTOC[toc]{\end{multicols}}
\tableofcontents{}
```

from [Two column toc in footnotesize with scrartcl: pagenumbers in toc are too large](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314029/two-column-toc-in-footnotesize-with-scrartcl-pagenumbers-in-toc-are-too-large/314046)