# Table of contents without title with 'tocloft' (class=report)

Tags: table-of-contents, titles, tocloft

I would like my Table of contents to be without any title and vertical space skipping. How can I do that with `tocloft` package?

I've seen [Table of contents without title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37935/table-of-contents-without-title), but code `\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{\@starttoc{toc}}` doesn't work for me. (presumably because of `tocloft` package?)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Redefine the "title making" macro:

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@cftmaketoctitle}{}
\makeatother
```

Comment: @rafaelm Please, add a minimal code showing what you're doing.