# remove table of contents header

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script

I have this document:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amstext}
\usepackage[locale=DE]{siunitx}
    \begin{document}
        \section{Mobilfunk - Was ist das?}
        \section{Kabellose \"Ubertragungsmethoden}
        \section{Bedeutung des Mobilfunks}
        \subsection{Gesundheitliche Faktoren}
        \section{Empfang und Abschirmung}
        \subsection{Feldst\"arkeunterschiede im Raum}
        \subsection{Beeinflussung der Feldst\"arke durch Umgebungsbedingungen}
        \section{Mobilfunknetze}
        \subsection{\"Offentliche und nicht-\"offentliche Mobilfunknetze}
        \subsection{SIM-Karten}
        \section{Visionen}
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

and returns that:

[image]

How can I remove the red framed header ("Inhaltsverzeichnis")?

Comment: Its a duplicat see:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50710/124842 Add the following to your preamble: 
`\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@cftmaketoctitle}{}
\makeatother`

Comment: @Bobyandbob This worked. Should I delete the question?

Comment: Yes you can delete the question and upvote the linked question and answer.

Comment: Please note, that `tocloft` and KOMA classes should not be used together. Decide for another class and `tocloft` or drop `tocloft` and keep `scrartcl`. Also `german` is an 'outdated' option to `babel`. Apply `ngerman` instead.

Comment: Also, this is insanity.

Comment: Remove `\usepackage{tocloft}` and add `\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\tocbasic@listhead@toc}[1]{}
\makeatother`. This is a documented feature of KOMA-Script package `tocbasic`. Every KOMA-Script class (like `scrartcl`) uses the package.

Comment: I do not think, that this is a real duplicate, because the other question is for `tocloft` only but here a KOMA-Script class is used and removing `tocloft` and using a solution without `tocloft` would be an recommended suggestion. See my previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use package `tocloft` together with a KOMA-Script class. You could use `\addtokomafont{sectionentry}{\rmfamily}` to change the font for the section entries in ToC.

Then you can use

```
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{\listoftoc*{toc}}
```

or

```
\deftocheading{toc}{}
```

to remove the ToC header.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern} 
%\usepackage{tocloft}% <- removed
\addtokomafont{sectionentry}{\rmfamily}% <- added
\deftocheading{toc}{}%<- added
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amstext}
\usepackage[locale=DE]{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\section{Mobilfunk - Was ist das?}
\section{Kabellose \"Ubertragungsmethoden}
\section{Bedeutung des Mobilfunks}
\subsection{Gesundheitliche Faktoren}
\section{Empfang und Abschirmung}
\subsection{Feldst\"arkeunterschiede im Raum}
\subsection{Beeinflussung der Feldst\"arke durch Umgebungsbedingungen}
\section{Mobilfunknetze}
\subsection{\"Offentliche und nicht-\"offentliche Mobilfunknetze}
\subsection{SIM-Karten}
\section{Visionen}
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```