# Two column toc in footnotesize with scrartcl: pagenumbers in toc are too large

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, multicol

I'd like to have a small table of contents in two columns. Everything looks as expected, except the pagenumbers in the toc: they are still at normalsize, instead of footnotesize, and still in rmfamily, instead of sffamily.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{multicol}

\BeforeStartingTOC[toc]{\begin{multicols}{2}\sffamily\footnotesize}%
\AfterStartingTOC[toc]{\end{multicols}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents{}

\blinddocument{}

\end{document}
```

Here is a screenshot from the PDF:

[image]

Any ideas how to tame the pagenumbers in the toc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since KOMA-Script version 3.20 there are new possiblities to format the TOC and list entries. You can use

```
\newcommand\fontintoc[1]{\sffamily\footnotesize #1}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[
    tocentryformat=\usekomafont{disposition}\fontintoc,
    tocpagenumberformat=\usekomafont{disposition}\fontintoc
]{part,section}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[
    tocentryformat=\fontintoc,
    tocpagenumberformat=\fontintoc
]{subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}[2016/05/10]

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{multicol}

\BeforeStartingTOC[toc]{\begin{multicols}{2}}%
\AfterStartingTOC[toc]{\end{multicols}}

\newcommand\fontintoc[1]{\sffamily\footnotesize #1}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[
    tocentryformat=\usekomafont{disposition}\fontintoc,
    tocpagenumberformat=\usekomafont{disposition}\fontintoc
]{part,section}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[
    tocentryformat=\fontintoc,
    tocpagenumberformat=\fontintoc
]{subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents{}
\blinddocument{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It took some time to find the information that I have to add a "toc" as a prefix to all the options of tabular 15.1 in scrguide. Instead of "indent=..." it is "tocindent=..." However, thank you!